# DisposableObserver dispose() not working (updates still received)

Tags: android, rx-java2

My callback (see `onResume()` below) is still getting called even after calling `dispose()` in `onPause()` of `MyFragment.java`. Why?

I don't think it's important, but: I call `NetworkUtils.subscribeToAvgPriceUpdates()` from multiple Fragments (only one is visible at once). In each Fragment I have one `DisposableObserver` and then when I switch to that fragment, I subscribe to data updates using that observer.

`NetworkUtils.java`:

```
public static void subscribeToAvgPriceUpdates(DisposableObserver<List<Result>> observer, CoinPriceUpdateCallback callback) {
    if(observer != null && !observer.isDisposed())
        observer.dispose();

    observer = new DisposableObserver<List<Result>>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(List<Result> results) {
            callback.onUpdated(results);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() { }
    };

    MainApplication.apiProvider.getAPI().getAllTickersRx()
            .repeatWhen(objectObservable -> objectObservable.delay(15000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) )
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(observer);
}
```

`MyFragment.java`:

```
private DisposableObserver<List<Result>> tickerUpdateObserver;

@Override
public void onPause () {
    if(tickerUpdateObserver != null)
        tickerUpdateObserver.dispose();

    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    NetworkUtils.subscribeToAvgPriceUpdates(tickerUpdateObserver, results -> {
        // still getting called even after I switch to another fragment, why?
        // shouldn't .dispose() in onPause() stop the updates?
    });
}
```

Comment: That looks strange: `observer = new ` where `observer` is a method argument, whereas you have `tickerUpdateObserver` field.

Comment: I though I could always just make a fresh new observer. Since it's an object, it's passed by reference.

Comment: Overwriting a method's argument inside a method has no effect on the original in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you create a new `DisposableObserver` inside the method but the field `tickerUpdateObserver` remains the same first instance, thus you don't have a reference to the newer observers.

You could just return the new `DisposableObserver` from the method and update the field:

```java
public static DisposableObserver<List<Result>> subscribeToAvgPriceUpdates(
        DisposableObserver<List<Result>> observer, 
        CoinPriceUpdateCallback callback) {
    if(observer != null && !observer.isDisposed())
        observer.dispose();

    observer = new DisposableObserver<List<Result>>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(List<Result> results) {
            callback.onUpdated(results);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() { }
    };

    MainApplication.apiProvider.getAPI().getAllTickersRx()
        .repeatWhen(objectObservable -> 
            objectObservable.delay(15000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) )
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(observer);

    return observer;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    tickerUpdateObserver = NetworkUtils.subscribeToAvgPriceUpdates(
            tickerUpdateObserver, results -> {
        // still getting called even after I switch to another fragment, why?
        // shouldn't .dispose() in onPause() stop the updates?
    });
}
```